# Hyperledger fabric channel creation problems

Tags: raspberry-pi, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to create network hyperledger on raspberry, to test it I began with basic-network downloaded from official hyperledger repository. I modified the docker-compose.yml file using the frbrkoala images version armv7l-1.0.1 from the official docker repo, but I have problem on the channel creation. My output is:

```
# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
2017-08-24 16:38:17.499 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-24 16:38:17.500 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-24 16:38:17.515 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2017-08-24 16:38:17.517 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 004 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-24 16:38:17.517 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 005 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-24 16:38:17.518 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 006 Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-24 16:38:17.518 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 007 Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-24 16:38:17.519 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0A8C060A074F7267314D53501280062D...53616D706C65436F6E736F727469756D 
2017-08-24 16:38:17.519 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: DE3AEEBF44C0CCB43E4EAA6497353CA8156DCC6AD6CC8E49ECD4306F313E2CD0 
2017-08-24 16:38:17.538 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00a Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-24 16:38:17.538 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00b Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-24 16:38:17.539 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP
2017-08-24 16:38:17.539 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
2017-08-24 16:38:17.540 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0AC3060A1508021A0608F981FCCC0522...4FF033E78ABA90BDB1577913810689E9 
2017-08-24 16:38:17.540 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: 8ADE9CA4E9BF4E3B87512B5B23FB102E30A0C72EFA8F9A587E4518986F02492D 
Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST
```

and the order logs are:

```
...
...
2017-08-24 16:38:18.757 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 195 Returning policy ChannelCreationPolicy for evaluation
2017-08-24 16:38:18.757 UTC [policies] CommitProposals -> DEBU 196 In commit adding relative sub-policy Application/ChannelCreationPolicy to Channel
2017-08-24 16:38:18.758 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 197 Returning policy Writers for evaluation
2017-08-24 16:38:18.758 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 198 Returning dummy reject all policy because Writers could not be found in /Application/Writers
2017-08-24 16:38:18.758 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 199 Returning dummy reject all policy because Admins could not be found in /Application/Admins
2017-08-24 16:38:18.758 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 19a Returning policy Admins for evaluation
2017-08-24 16:38:18.758 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 19b Returning policy Readers for evaluation
2017-08-24 16:38:18.758 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 19c Returning dummy reject all policy because Readers could not be found in /Application/Readers
2017-08-24 16:38:18.758 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 19d Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel
2017-08-24 16:38:18.765 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 19e Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application
2017-08-24 16:38:18.767 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 19f Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/Org1MSP
2017-08-24 16:38:18.767 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a0 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/Org2MSP
2017-08-24 16:38:18.768 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a1 Adding to config map: [Values] /Channel/Consortium
2017-08-24 16:38:18.768 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a2 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel
2017-08-24 16:38:18.768 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a3 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application
2017-08-24 16:38:18.769 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a4 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/Org1MSP
2017-08-24 16:38:18.769 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a5 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/Org2MSP
2017-08-24 16:38:18.770 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a6 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Application/Admins
2017-08-24 16:38:18.770 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a7 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Application/Writers
2017-08-24 16:38:18.770 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a8 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Application/Readers
2017-08-24 16:38:18.771 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 1a9 Adding to config map: [Values] /Channel/Consortium
2017-08-24 16:38:18.771 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 1aa Rejecting CONFIG_UPDATE because: Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: invalid mod_policy for element [Policy] /Channel/Application/Admins: mod_policy not set
2017-08-24 16:38:18.772 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 1ab Closing Broadcast stream
2017-08-24 16:38:18.788 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 1ac Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2017-08-24 16:38:18.789 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 1ad Closing Deliver stream
```

I think that the problem are in the last 4 lines. Someone can help me please? thank you.

Comment: What version of "configtxgen" are you using?  You can find it using `configtxgen -version`

Comment: I haven't because I didn't find a version that works on raspberry.. I'm using the original artifact generate for the basic network and fabcar example